# Adobe omniture - trying to fire evar and events in the s_code file doesn't work

Tags: javascript, adobe, adobe-analytics

I have successfully implemented on-click events tracking on Omniture. s.eVar62 and s.prop62 fires with a text string each time a link is clicked that has the tracking code enabled.

I want to extend this functionality in the s_code to fire another evar (s.eVar76) when on-click is fired with a specific text value.

```
console.log('s.eVar62 is ' + s.eVar62);
// track existing customers
if (s.eVar62) {
    if (s.eVar62.indexOf('credit card login') > -1) {
        s.eVar76 = 'credit card customer';
        if (s.events) s.events = s.apl(s.events, "event104", ",", 2);
    }
    if (s.eVar62.indexOf('super member login') > -1) {
        s.eVar76 = 'super member customer';
        if (s.events) s.events = s.apl(s.events, "event105", ",", 2);
    }
    if (s.eVar62.indexOf('super employer login') > -1) {
        s.eVar76 = 'super employer customer';
        if (s.events) s.events = s.apl(s.events, "event106", ",", 2);
    }
    if (s.eVar62.indexOf('home loans login') > -1) {
        s.eVar76 = 'home loans customer';
        if (s.events) s.events = s.apl(s.events, "event107", ",", 2);
    }
    if (s.eVar62.indexOf('savings login') > -1) {
        s.eVar76 = 'savings customer';
        if (s.events) s.events = s.apl(s.events, "event108", ",", 2);
    }
    console.log('eVar76 is ' + s.eVar76);
    console.log('s.events are ' + s.events);
}
```

in the code there, you can see I've logged things to the console to see what's happening.

I seem to be seeing positive results in the console but the values don't get tracked in the reporting. As in, in the reporting, s.eVar76 is empty even though evar62 is tracking properly with the correct strings.

Can anyone point me in the right direction as to what I am doing wrong? Thanks.

**UPDATE 2015-06-12**

Based on some members' comments and suggestions, I have edited the s_code again to this:

```
// track existing customers
if (s.eVar62) {
    s.linkTrackVars += ',eVar76';
    if (s.eVar62.indexOf('credit card login') > -1) {
        s.linkTrackEvents += ',event104';
        s.eVar76 = 'credit card customer';
        if (s.events) s.events = s.apl(s.events, "event104", ",", 2);
    }
    if (s.eVar62.indexOf('super member login') > -1) {
        s.linkTrackEvents += ',event105';
        s.eVar76 = 'super member customer';
        if (s.events) s.events = s.apl(s.events, "event105", ",", 2);
    }
    if (s.eVar62.indexOf('super employer login') > -1) {
        s.linkTrackEvents += ',event106';
        s.eVar76 = 'super employer customer';
        if (s.events) s.events = s.apl(s.events, "event106", ",", 2);
    }
    if (s.eVar62.indexOf('home loans login') > -1) {
        s.linkTrackEvents += ',event107';
        s.eVar76 = 'home loans customer';
        if (s.events) s.events = s.apl(s.events, "event107", ",", 2);
    }
    if (s.eVar62.indexOf('savings login') > -1) {
        s.linkTrackEvents += ',event108';
        s.eVar76 = 'savings customer';
        if (s.events) s.events = s.apl(s.events, "event108", ",", 2);
    }
}
```

but still no luck. Any more ideas?

Comment: Did you add eVar76 to [`s.linkTrackVars`](https://marketing.adobe.com/resources/help/en_US/sc/implement/linkTrackVars.html)?

Comment: I have but only included evar62 and prop62 and this was done in the actual onclick function. in the s_code, i haven't added in s.linkTrackVars in there.

Comment: And **s.linkTrackEvents** have to contain **"events"**

Comment: put this at the very end of your `s_doPlugins` function: `console.log('linkTrackVars: ',s.linkTrackVars);console.log('linkTrackEvents: ',s.linkTrackEvents);`  what does it show?

Comment: So, to re-iterate, when a button is clicked, the on-click event is fired and evar62 is fired. This is successful. The firing of the on-click executes s_doplugins. So far so good. Inside s_doplugins, I have a condition that checks if evar62 exists and if it does, makes evar76 equal a text string, which value is dependent on what value evar62 has. Based on previous replies, I have now also added s.linkTrackVars and s.linkTrackEvents to declare evar76.

Comment: when I do the console.log, this is what I get:

linkTrackVars:  events,eVar62,prop62,eVar76,eVar76

linkTrackEvents:  event2,event104,event104

weird that it should repeat evar 76 and event 104 twice.

Comment: just speculation seeing as how i can't look at your site, but my guess is you have AA auto-link tracking enabled so there's 2 separate calls being made, and since you are appending the values to a running list, it's getting appended twice. It's not *really* harmful for them to be in there twice like that..unless I'm right about double requests and the data is in both.. that would mean inflated numbers. On that note.. do you see 2 separate requests to AA being made? Do you see your vars? In both?

Comment: you need to look at the actual http request being made to AA. You can look at the net tab on the browser console, or use Adobe DigitalPulse, Omnibug, Charles Proxy, or any number of packet sniffer tools.

Comment: also, I mentioned console logging linkTrackVars and linkTrackEvents at the very end of s_doPlugins because that should be the last "public facing" code executed before the s.tl call.  Also console log s.events and your vars there. Do they have values? If not, then something else is overwriting them somewhere. If so, then they should be in the AA http request.  If you see them, and you still aren't seeing data in your reports.. are you sure it's being sent to the right report suite? Check the rsid in the http request

Comment: If you've done all that, and it all looks legit, start checking your interface settings. Are the events/evars enabled? Are the events set to always record? What is the expiration of the evar? attribution? etc. lot of those settings affect how/when/if the data shows up in the reports. Do you have any processing rules setup that are overwriting them?  Are they being used somewhere else on the site so the values may not be "winning" (attribution)?  There are a million other things to check, go down the list.

Comment: In addition to what @CrayonViolent said (especially checking the actual request to Adobe), since you're using one of the newer variables (event100+, eVar75+) you need to be on the latest core code. The older ones will _not_ pass in the higher variables in the request. Also, if you could post the URL this is happening on that'd help a lot ;)

Comment: Where can I download the latest core code from?

Comment: If you login to Adobe Analytics, navigate to the Admin section then Code Manager. Shortcut links: [Latest AppMeasurement](https://sc.omniture.com/p/appmeasurement/current/GetComponent.html?platform=js&component=AppMeasurement_JavaScript.zip), or the [Latest H Code (Legacy)](https://sc.omniture.com/p/appmeasurement/current/GetComponent.html?platform=js&component=AppMeasurement_Legacy_JavaScript.zip)